# How to Copy format from remote CVS to local file eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, cvs, format, compare

I am new to eclipse. I checked in java file from remote CVS.then I modify the file
 then I compare with latest from head.
 the comparison highlight of the file even parts I didn't change.

How to Copy format from remote CVS to local file eclipse ? any ideas ?

thanks in advance,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling "Ignore white space" under Window : Preferences : General : Compare/Patch.
Also avoid doing Source : Format or Source : Cleanup before doing your compare.

Edit: Also, it's possible to export/import formatting preferences in eclipse.  You may want to ask the author of the code if they would be willing to provide their exported preferences.